# PromQL query between two date ranges only

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to figure out how to create a PromQL query that will query between 10 days ago and 3 days ago only.I don't want any data of the last 3 days included.

I've tried offset, but every query I run seems to use the current time and then work backwards from that.